# Customize section numbering in TOC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering

I'm working with `report` class and I would like to customize headings of chapters, sections and subsections, abvoe all the look of numbers before their respective headings, both in the text and in the contents.

### My Probolem

I've customized `\thechapter`, `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` like that:

```
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Ordinalstring{chapter}}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{%
        \textls{%
            \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont%
            \Numberstring{chapter}.\numberstring{section}%
        }%
    }
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{%
        \textls[100]{%
            \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{11pt}{13.2pt}\selectfont%
            \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}%
        }%
    }
```

Now, for table of contents I would like to have a different look for these counters. That's to say, I would like my index looks like this:

```
Chapter 1
  Title of Chapter                                              thepage
  1.1
    Title of Section .......................................... thepage
    1.1.1
      Title of Subsection ..................................... thepage
```

For chapters I've changed the addcontentsline declaration in `\@chapter` definition as follows:

```
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{Chapter \arabic{chapter}}\newline\hspace*{.7em} #1} % space is not exact for the time being
```

and so in toc I have ''Chapter 1'', ''Chapter 2'' and so on.

I would like to make the same thing for sections and subsections.

### Using `titlesec` and `titletoc` packages

After some research I've found `titlesec` and `titletoc` packages and using them my code is this:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
    \usepackage{fmtcount}
    %
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Ordinalstring{chapter}}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{%
        \textls{%
            \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont%
            \Numberstring{chapter}.\numberstring{section}%
        }%
    }
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{%
        \textls[100]{%
            \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{11pt}{13.2pt}\selectfont%
            \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}%
        }%
    }
    \usepackage[rigidchapters,nobottomtitles*,pageatnewline]{titlesec}
        \titlespacing*{\section}
                      {0em}
                      {2em}
                      {0.5em}
        \titlespacing*{\subsection}
                      {0em}
                      {2em}
                      {0.5em}
        \titleformat{\section}
                    [display]
                    {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{11pt}{13.2pt}\selectfont}
                    {\thesection}
                    {1ex}
                    {}
                    {}
        \titleformat{\subsection}
                    [display]
                    {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{11pt}{13.2pt}\selectfont}
                    {\thesubsection}
                    {0em}
                    {}
                    {}
    %
    \usepackage{titletoc}
        \titlecontents{chapter}
                      [0em]
                      {\bfseries}
                      {Chapter \thecontentslabel\\*\hspace*{.7em}}
                      {}
                      {\hfill\contentspage}
        \titlecontents{section}
                      [1.5em]
                      {}
                      {\thecontentslabel\\*\hspace*{.7em}}
                      {}
                      {\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
        \titlecontents*{subsection}
                      [3.8em]
                      {}
                      {\thecontentslabel\\*\hspace*{.7em}}
                      {}
                      {\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
    %
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Foo}

    \lipsum[1]

    \section{Bar}

    \lipsum[2]

    \subsection{Qux}

    \lipsum[3]

    \section{Quux}

    \lipsum[4]

    \subsection{Quux1}

    \lipsum[5]

    \chapter{foo}

    \section{bar}

    \lipsum[4]

    \subsection{qux}

    \lipsum[5]

    \tableofcontents
    \end{document}
```

Here I don't want to change the `\thechapter` contents for toc, but only for sections and subsectios (anyway I could change chapter counter for toc as I made above in `\@chapter` definition and so, declaring `\titlecontents{}[]{}{}{}{}` for `chapter` as above, `\thecontentslabel` would contain arabic numbers for chapters).

I've thought to customize `\thecontentslabel` or the definition of `\numberline` (at line 433 in `titletoc.sty`) in `\ttl@tocentry`.

As I undersand it, `\numberline`  is responsible for printing numbers of sections and subsections in toc, but I don't know how to redefine it...

It would be possible to redefine `\thecontentslabel` only for sections and subsection?

Please, could I have an explanation about the behavior of `\thecontentslabel`, expecially its definition?

If I try to declare `\thecontentslabel` after `\begin{document}`, why does `\LaTeX` give me this error message?

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.76 \thecontentslabel
```

### Some attempts

I've tried with this:

```
    \newcommand{\originalthecontentslabel}{}
    \global\let\originalthecontentslabel\thecontentslabel
    \gdef\thecontentslabel#1{\originalcontentslabel{\arabic{#1}}}
```

but it seems not to be considered by `\LaTeX`. I think that `titletoc` overwrites my re-definition (I've tried to put it first beforse `titletoc` and then after it, but it's not considered).

Then, I've tried with this:

```
    \def\numberline##1{\global\ttl@labeltrue\gdef\thecontentslabel{\@arabic##1}}%
```

and this:

```
    \def\numberline##1{\global\ttl@labeltrue\gdef\thecontentslabel{\arabic{##1}}}%
```

but they don't work and `\LaTeX` prints this error message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\let
l.2 ...{\numberline {\Ordinalstringnum {1}}Foo}{1}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

### Summary

In summary,

- how to edit sections and subsection counters in order to have different formats for their numbers in the table of contents without using `titletoc`?
- how to make the same thing in the above item with `titletoc` (or other suitable package...)?

Hope to have been carefull enought!

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely *not* a good idea to define `\thesection` with formatting instructions. Also, you want to have `\thechapter` to expand to `\arabic{chapter}`, so that you need to change its appearance only when typesetting the chapter head.

Here are some changes to your settings. However, I don't like at all the way section and subsection titles are set, but the document is yours.

1. No redefinition of `\thechapter`, `\thesection` and `\thesubsection`
2. The `\@makechapterhead` is patched to print `\Ordinalstring{chapter}` instead of `\thechapter`.
3. Some tidying of the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\thechapter}
  {\Ordinalstring{chapter}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[rigidchapters,nobottomtitles*,pageatnewline]{titlesec}

\titlespacing*{\section}
              {0em}
              {2em}
              {0.5em}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
              {0em}
              {2em}
              {0.5em}
\titleformat{\section}
            [display]
            {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{11pt}{13.2pt}\selectfont}
            {\thesection}
            {1ex}
            {}
            {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
            [display]
            {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{11pt}{13.2pt}\selectfont}
            {\thesubsection}
            {0em}
            {}
            {}
%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
              [0em]
              {\bfseries}
              {Chapter \thecontentslabel\\*\hspace*{.7em}}
              {}
              {\hfill\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}
              [1.5em]
              {}
              {{\sffamily\thecontentslabel}\\*\hspace*{.7em}}
              {}
              {\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents*{subsection}
              [3.8em]
              {}
              {{\sffamily\thecontentslabel}\\*\hspace*{.7em}}
              {}
              {\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
%

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Bar}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Qux}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Quux}

\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Quux1}

\lipsum[5]

\chapter{foo}

\section{bar}

\lipsum[4]

\subsection{qux}

\lipsum[5]

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! As a matter of fact, I had thought to use a local redefinition of `\thechapter`, `\thesection` and `\thesubsection`, but I ignored how to do that and where I could look... I've just tried `\patchcm` for `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` and that's all ok, thank you! I'm agree with you about the look of this layout, but it was asked to me about thus. Please, could you explain to me why it's not a good idea define `\thesection` with formatting instructions?

Comment: @OnnerIrotsab `\thesection`, like other `\the...` commands associated to counters is used to define labels for cross references. So it should only produce the "number" (maybe composite with other numbers) and not intructions on how to print it. Printing the numbers is done in other places: in your case use `\titleformat` for telling LaTeX how to print the section number.

Comment: You've been very clear, thank you very much!

Comment: @OnnerIrotsab We live not too far from each other (at least as academic work is concerned), did you know?

Comment: Yes, I know that! Also, I know about you because of your book on LaTeX programming, that I'm reading, and for your several and very very usefull answers I've found online!

Answer (score 3):

Below there's one possible solution using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft).

- The redefinitions for `\thechapter`, `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` are made locally and only for the headings, inside the corresponding `\titleformat` command.
- To change the formatting for the ToC entries I used `tocloft` instead of `titletoc` since the former interacts in a better way with `hyperref`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen} 

\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\par\noindent}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}

\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnumb{%
  \par\noindent\hspace*{-0.5\cftsecnumwidth}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecaftersnumb{%
  \par\noindent\hspace*{-0.5\cftsubsecnumwidth}}

\cftsetindents{subsection}{\dimexpr0.5\cftsecnumwidth+0.5\cftsubsecnumwidth\relax}{1.5em}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Ordinalstring{chapter}}
\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{11pt}{13.2pt}\selectfont}{\renewcommand{\thesection}{%
        \textls{%
            \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{9pt}{10.8pt}\selectfont%
            \Numberstring{chapter}.\numberstring{section}%
        }%
    }
\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{11pt}{13.2pt}\selectfont}{\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{%
        \textls[100]{%
            \fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{11pt}{13.2pt}\selectfont%
            \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}%
        }%
    }
\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One One}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One One}
\section{Test Section Two Two}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two One}

\end{document}
```

The ToC:

[image]

An inner page showing the modified headings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I don't believe I'll have to use `hyperref`, however good to know about `tocloft` in combination with `hyperref`! I've tried to put `\renewcommand{\thesection}{...}` in `\tileformat` as you have made, but then I've not called `\thesecion` in `\titleformat` and I've not deleted the previous redefinitions of `\thesection` and `\thesubsection`... I didn't think this could have been the solution and so I've left it go.